# What's the simplest way to produce 150VDC for activating my piezo stack?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, piezo, step-up

I recently bought a piezo stack for research purposes. To activate the piezo stack and get the maximum stroke I have to supply 150VDC.

I want to use the piezo stack in two states only: 0V and 150VDC.

- What is the simplest way to achieve this? AC to DC or AC to DC to DC?
- Which components do I have to buy / how do I calculate which specifications my components should have?

Edit:
The switching time isn't important. I just need this to work for a test setup. The test setup contains levers to amplify the stroke of the piezoelectric stack.

The two states (0V and 150V) should be achieved by an ON (for 150V)/OFF (for 0V)-switch.

I prefer using the mains voltage (230VAC) as the power supply.

I got many different piezostacks. The one I am using right now is the PK4FA2P1 from Thorlabs:

- Crossection (Square): 5mm x 5mm
- Length: 11mm
- Capacitance: 750nF

[image: Piezostack PK4FA2P1 (Thorlabs)]

Comment: Simple is relative. How fast do you want to switch between the two states? Is this a manual operation or controlled via electronics?

Comment: How large (size and capacitance) is the piezo?  A model number would be ideal.  Please click the [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/629742/edit) link below your question to address comments, thank you.

Comment: I guess the simplest way would be to buy a cheap lab supply that can put out 150 V. If you live in north america or japan, you could just rectify AC from your power outlet, then add a capacitor to get something like 150 V. But there are a lot of details to see to. Particularly, limiting inrush.

Comment: What options do you already have or would prefer to use for primary power sources? Mains, batteries, USB ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would divide your question:

> What is the *simplest way* to achieve this? AC to DC or AC to DC to DC?

**Two points in this discussion:**

---

**(1) Generating a 150VDC as the Max. Driving voltage**.
For this, I would guess *the simplest way is to use an isolation transformer* - or make one using 2 small power transformers, where the low voltage sides are connected together.
**For this simplest way**: You have an isolated AC, which should be rectified, filtered and stabilized to not go above the Max. rated voltage of 150 VDC, as said [here, under “operation” tab](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=8040).

**However, if** you wish to generate a **Higher DC from a battery-operated or DC power supply**, several step-up circuits could be used. They are NOT the simplest circuit as you asked, but being DC-DC, the use of an inductor may be the easiest approach (compared with Diode-based voltage multipliers).  Probably the cheapest inductor-based HighVoltage PS could be adapted from a [Joule Thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief). Combine your search with Neon lamp and you will find circuits delivering voltages close to what you need.

---

**(2) Operating the Piezo Stack with 150VDC**.
If energy consumption is not critical, I would choose to leave the HV PS already powered on, then commute a Bipolar or MOSFET transistor to drive On-Off your piezo stack. This gives the fastest response time.
**If delays are acceptable** from 0.1-1.0s (transformer) up to 5-10s (Low power step-up / ‘Joule thief’), **or** the wasted energy (as from a battery) is important, **then** I would consider driving the stack by powering On-Off the power supply itself.